# Video not shown up in Photogallery in android app

Tags: titanium-mobile

Why I am not be able to see videos in Android app's from photogallery. The code i have used is as follows.
.

```
Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({
            success:function(event)  //success event
            {             
                Ti.API.debug('Our type was: '+event.mediaType);
                if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO,Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
                {
                    UploadPhotoToServer(event.media);
                }
            },
            cancel:function()
            {   
            },
            error:function(err)
            {
                Ti.API.error(err);
            },
            mediaTypes:[Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO,Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO]
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

**This** is no valid JS.

```
if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO,Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
{
    UploadPhotoToServer(event.media);
}
```

Change to

```
if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO || event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
{
    UploadPhotoToServer(event.media);
}
```

(see if clause)

Comment: This also didn't show the video in the photogallary. Is there any alternative for showing videos in the gallery.    Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Please have a look in [Android Monitor](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html).

Comment: NO error message at all..Video just shown for a second and hide fron the photo gallary..

Answer (score 0):

On Android, using Intent

```
var intent = Titanium.Android.createIntent({
        action : Ti.Android.ACTION_PICK,
        type : "video/*"
    });

    intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    var activity = Titanium.Android.currentActivity;
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, function(e) { if (e.error) { ...} else { ...}}:
```